# Assigning a collection of images to a code-behind property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collections

Okay, so I have been struggling for days to figure out how XAML is actually processing collections, and every single time I try the DependencyProperty method, the property is null. When I use ObservableCollection, and assign it a type of an Array in XAML, I get a message stating that type ArrayExtension can not be assigned to collection or dictionary.

So I am now sitting at a point where I don't know what I don't know, but I know my objective.

I want to assign multiple elements of type `<Image />` to my collection in code-behind, and I have to be able to identify (preferably by integer) which "image" is being referenced in the collection.

Preferable XAML format.

```
<cc:MyControl.States>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource PointBulletIconImage}" />
    <Image Source="{StaticResource PointNumberIconImage}" />
</cc:MyControl.States>
```

Code-behind desired functionality

```
this.Image = States[CurrentState];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have removed a tag from your question's title. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: given your names i suspect your desired behaviour is to show a different icon depending on a state property in which case i would suggest a Value Converter where you feed in the state and get back an image source or URI then just bind the images image source to the status property

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a collection of Image controls, your control should declare a property that holds a collection of `ImageSource` objects, like

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public List<ImageSource> States { get; } = new List<ImageSource>();

    ...
}
```

You could now add bitmap resources in XAML like this:

```
<cc:MyControl>
    <cc:MyControl.States>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PointBulletIconImage"/>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PointNumberIconImage"/>
    </cc:MyControl.States>
</cc:MyControl>
```

The XAML of MyControl would declare an `Image` control, e.g. named "image"

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

and you would set its `Source` property in code behind like this:

```
image.Source = States[0];
```

Comment: I was completely unaware that StaticResource could be used as an element. Black magic mate. I am gonna try this solution first, then Mike T's when I get home if it doesn't work. I'll get back to you. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: So, it's syntactically sound, but for some reason, it's still a null value. I compile the code, and for some reason, the list does not ever get populated. With a dependencyproperty and with I being on its own.

Comment: Maybe you didn't initialize the dependency property to a new list instance. Don't do this by setting a default value via property metadata, but by an assignment in the MyControl constructor.

Comment: I thought by registering the dependency property, it's automatically initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so as per Clemens's suggestion, I figured it out. The issue was that I wasn't "waiting" until after the element was loaded. It initializes the components, then takes in values, which I was forgetting. As a result, the values that are being assigned don't yet exist. Clemen's solution to use the  to an ImageSource observable collection worked, but I had to wait until the control was loaded.

```
public ImageSource ImageSource {
        get {
            return GetValue(ImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource;
        }
        set {
            SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> States { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

    public int CurrentState { get; set; }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty  = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(PointButton));
    public PointButton( ) {
        CurrentState = 0;
        InitializeComponent( );
        Loaded += PointButton_Loaded;
    }

    private void PointButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        PreviewMouseUp += PointButton_MouseUp;
        UpdateLayout( );
        if(States == null)
            Console.WriteLine("States is null");
        else
            ImageSource = States[CurrentState];
    }

    private void PointButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if(CurrentState == States.Count - 1)
            CurrentState = 0;
        else
            CurrentState += 1;
        ImageSource = States[CurrentState];
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Button x:Class="Notes.Views.Controls.PointButton"
    x:Name="RootElement"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Notes.Views.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         >
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, ElementName=RootElement}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

So, I got it working. Thanks for the responses guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your names I suspect your desired behaviour is to show a different icon depending on a state property in which case you really want to leave the code behind out of it as much as possible.

I would suggest a Value Converter where you feed in the state and get back an image source or URI then just bind the images image source to the status property

here is a complete example of what this would look like 
Note: Example uses c#6 syntax

```
WPF:

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="img1" UriSource="someimg1.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="img2" UriSource="someimg2.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="img3" UriSource="someimg3.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="img4" UriSource="someimg4.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="img5" UriSource="someimg5.png" />
        <local:StateImageConverter 
            x:Key="StateImageConverter"
            State1Image="{StaticResource img1}"
            State2Image="{StaticResource img2}"
            State3Image="{StaticResource img3}"
            State4Image="{StaticResource img4}"
            State5Image="{StaticResource img5}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VeiwModel x:Name="viewModel" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllStates}" SelectedValue="{Binding State}"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StateImageConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public enum States
{
    State1,
    State2,
    State3,
    State4,
    State5,
}

public class StateImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ImageSource State1Image { get; set; }
    public ImageSource State2Image { get; set; }
    public ImageSource State3Image { get; set; }
    public ImageSource State4Image { get; set; }
    public ImageSource State5Image { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var state = value as States?;
        if(state.HasValue)
        {
            switch (state.Value)
            {
                case States.State1:
                    return State1Image;
                case States.State2:
                    return State2Image;
                case States.State3:
                    return State3Image;
                case States.State4:
                    return State4Image;
                case States.State5:
                    return State5Image;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidCastException();
            }
        }
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //one way only
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class VeiwModel : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private States state;

    public States State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("State"));
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<States> AllStates=> Enum.GetValues(typeof(States)).OfType< States>();

}
```

Or if you don't want to use named properties then a variation using a list would look like:

```
public class StateImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var state = value as States?;
        if(state.HasValue)
        {
            return Images[(int)state.Value];
        }
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //one way only
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

defined as

```
<local:StateImageConverter 
            x:Key="StateImageConverter">
            <local:StateImageConverter.Images>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="someimg1.png" />
                <BitmapImage UriSource="someimg2.png" />
                <BitmapImage UriSource="someimg3.png" />
                <BitmapImage UriSource="someimg4.png" />
                <BitmapImage UriSource="someimg5.png" />
            </local:StateImageConverter.Images>
        </local:StateImageConverter>
```

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if I wished to use a collection for the states, how would I go about doing this's?

Comment: Sorry, on my iPad at the moment for typing. My intended goal is to have an image button where the image cycles through an undetermined amount of images. Each image is bound to a state, and the state has to be read externally.

Comment: if your item can be in multiple states simultaneously then you would have an items control such as listview and then use the items template to define the binding